# Setting a cookie with nookies in Next.js api folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am trying to set a cookie with `nookies` npm package using Next.js api folder. I already used a similar code to set up a cookie with the `nookies` and it worked just fine. For some reason it does not work in this case. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Let me know if you have any ideas.

```
import { parseCookies, setCookie } from 'nookies';
import { paymentIntent } from '@/Models/Stripe';
import { cartByUser } from '@/Models/Cart';
import { currentUser } from '@/Models/User';

export const createPaymentIntentController = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.user;
  const { couponApplied } = req.body;

  const { appPaymentIntentId } = parseCookies({req});
  console.log({ appPaymentIntentId });

  try {
    const user = await currentUser(email);
    const cart = await cartByUser(user._id);
    const result = await paymentIntent(cart, couponApplied, appPaymentIntentId);

    if (!appPaymentIntentId) {
      console.log('result.paymentIntent.id: ', result.paymentIntent.id); // pi_1JFc5jJM2kZsXGkUm18Z8B2J typeof string

      setCookie({ res }, 'appPaymentIntentId', result.paymentIntent.id, {
        // maxAge: 72576000,
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
      });
    }

    res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`createPaymentIntentController error: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Is your app and api on same domain?

Comment: same domain, I am using Next api folder

Comment: hey, are you mixing serverside with client-only cookies? try to see nookies here https://github.com/maticzav/nookies

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
nookies.set(
  {res}, 
  'appPaymentIntentId',
  result.paymentIntent.id, 
  { httpOnly: true, path: '/' }
)
```

to set server-side cookies

Comment: Can you expand on this answer as to why?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).